# SQL Add a column to dynamically get value from another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
LV1 | LV2 | LV3 
A   | B   |C
X   |Y    |Null
```

I want to add a column to get the bottom level,

```
LV1 | LV2 | LV3 |Bottom
A   | B   |C    |C
X   |Y    |Null |Y
```

How should I do that?  - I am using SQL Server

Thanks

Comment: bottom-level means???  did you tried anything, if so show us.

Comment: is there any specific condition or logic to get the column value? and also do you want this in your table itself or in select query?

Comment: @jasmine,I post answer for your question.Try that query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use CTE to get your result :

```
 CREATE TABLE #table(LV1 VARCHAR(10) ,LV2 VARCHAR(10) , LV3 VARCHAR(10))
 INSERT INTO #table(LV1  ,LV2  , LV3)
 SELECT 'A','B','C' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'X','Y',null

 ;WITH CTE (LV1  ,LV2  , LV3 , Bottom) AS
 (
   SELECT LV1  ,LV2  , LV3 , COALESCE(LV3,LV2,LV1)
   FROM #table
 ) 

 SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Comment: Thanks. This COALESCE is what I am looking for!

Answer (score 3):

```
 CREATE TABLE #table(LV1 VARCHAR(10) ,LV2 VARCHAR(10) , LV3 VARCHAR(10))
 INSERT INTO #table(LV1  ,LV2  , LV3)
 SELECT 'A','B','C' UNION ALL
 SELECT 'X','Y',null
 SELECT LV1  ,LV2  , LV3 , COALESCE(LV3,LV2,LV1) Bottom
 FROM #table
```

output

```
LV1 LV2 LV3 Bottom
A   B   C       C
X   Y   NULL    Y
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a function and then call this function for the default value:

```
alter table yourTable
add constraint 
df_Bottom_Default
default([dbo].[your_udf_function]())
for Bottom
```